# Rails 3 best practice to modify a boolean attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, boolean

What is the best practice to switch a boolean attribute e.g., un-/publish an article?

For the Model side, I saw `Object.update_attribute(:only_one_field, 'my_value')` is best for this job, instead of `update_attributes`.

What about

1. the View (use a link, a submit button in a form, other ideas?) and
2. the Controller side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Views usually use forms for updating models.  The [`form_for` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) makes this pretty straightforward.
2. If you are using a standard update action (your controller inherits from `InheritedResources::Base`) then your update! method in your controller should handle this fine.

I would actually advise against using `Model.update_attribute(:published, value)` unless you are aware that this call bypasses your model's validations.  This is generally why forms just post to the update or create methods in the controller - those by default go through the entire ActiveRecord lifecycle, calling your validations as well.  If you have a reason to bypass them, then by all means use `update_attribute`.

Comment: Yes, aware of the validation bypassing: the Rails API says that `update_attribute` *updates [...] and saves the record without going through the normal validation procedure. This is especially useful for boolean flags on existing records.* That's why I think it fits best this scenario.